# TSQL - do query on result set from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say if using sp_helplognis, want to view result set with filter `UserName=db_owner`. Is there any way besides output the original result set to a temp table and then query on that temp table? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use sp_helplogins: use [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786(SQL.90).aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM  sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'bob'
```

If you want the 2nd resultset of sp_helplogins, then you'd have to use c# or something because loading a temp table will only trap the 1st resultset.

The equivalent of sys.server_principals is [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328(SQL.90).aspx) too

FYI: db_owner is in every database already. What are you really trying to do...?

Edit, after comment, something like:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDb '
USE ?
IF DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID (''myloginname'') IS NOT NULL
  EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''myloginname''
'
```

Comment: I want to find what databases are belongs to a specific user and run below script: <code>USE DbName
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, myloginname
GO</code>

Answer (score 1):

You can divert the resultset of a sproc into a new table, e.g.

```
create table #results (...)
insert into #results execute myproc
select * from #results where ...
```

It's a bit fiddly because you have to reverse-engineer the resultset data types pretty exactly to avoid casting errors.

Comment: What if the SP returns 2 result sets?

Comment: So what would people do if they need refine the SP output result set?

Comment: I have just checked MSDN, and it appears that all resultsets are loaded into the one table. That's no use if the resultsets differ in column definitions I'm afraid.